# Storing binary data with metadata

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first, lazy-loading

Using Entity Framework 4.2 Code First, we want to store some image data in our database. The images are small, and are cached on disk whenever we can.

However, we quite frequently need some metadata stored with the image (e.g. it's MIME type), but not the actual image data.

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    //...
    public Image Image { get; set; }
}

public class Image
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public String MimeType { get; set; }

   public byte[] Bytes { get; set; }
}

// this also loads Bytes:
var item = _db.Items.Include("Image").Find(1);
var mimeType = item.Image.MimeType;
```

Specifically, we only want the actual `Bytes` of the image in very rare cases, and thus do not want this to load unless we request it.

What is the best practice for avoiding loading `Bytes` when you need actual `Image` objects?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My recommendation is that you create a separate entity (e.g. ImageBytes with Id and Bytes) specifically for the field that contains the Bytes and make that related to the Image entity (which has Id and MimeType). You can use a feature called Table Splitting (in EDMX and in COde First) where you can map multiple entities to a single database table. Then you can query the Image entities and EF will only select the necessary columns from the database. You can access the Bytes through the relationship you define between Image and ImageBytes. Then you can either do eager loading, lazy loading or explicit loading to retrieve the imagebytes.

If you're using data annotations, all you have to do is specify the table for both entities:

```
[Table("Image")]
public class Image
{}

[Table("Image")]
public class ImageBytes
{}
```

With fluent API

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Image>()
            .HasRequired(e => e.Bytes)
            .WithRequiredPrincipal();

modelBuilder.Entity<Image>().ToTable("Image");
modelBuilder.Entity<ImageBytes>().ToTable("Image");
```

hth
julie

Comment: This was just what we needed. We ended up mixing fluent and data annotations, because we couldn't find the equivalent for the `HasRequired` and `WithRequiredPrincipal` as data annotations.

Comment: ahh yeah ...by default, code first doesn't know what to do about 1:1 relationships if you don't give it some clues (either in code so that convention can pick it up or in a configuration) about which is the principal and which is the dependent. If you wanted to stick to Data ANnotations, you could mark the Id property of the ImageBytes class as ForeignKey and that would be enough info for convention to say "ahh that must be the dependent"